# How do I install SIPSAK with macports?

Tags: terminal, xcode, install, homebrew, macports

For context, SIPSAK is the SIP Swiss Army Knife:

> sipsak is a command line tool which can send simple requests to a SIP
>   server. It can run additional tests on a SIP server which are usefull
>   for admins and developers of SIP enviroments.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/sipsak.berlios/

[SIPSAK](https://github.com/sipwise/sipsak) seems to work with macports:

```
 acinclude.m4   added mac port dirs to search paths     7 years ago
```

at least [according to their github web page](https://github.com/nils-ohlmeier/sipsak).

Do I have to build [SIPSAK](https://github.com/sipwise/sipsak) from source?  Or, is there a binary repository I can add and then install from, using, perhaps, the command line?

I was looking at [macports](https://www.macports.org/), I think that's how this is done.

Will this finally allow me to add binary repositories to install software, like sipsak?  Strictly speaking, I'm not trying to compile sipsak, just use it.

Will macports allow me to install it?

MacPorts 2.3.3

and the system I'm using:

```
System Software Overview:

  System Version:   Mac OS X 10.7.5 (11G63)
  Kernel Version:   Darwin 11.4.2
  Boot Volume:  Untitled
  Boot Mode:    Normal
  Computer Name:    a MacBook
  User Name:    thufir (thufir)
  Secure Virtual Memory:    Enabled
  64-bit Kernel and Extensions: No
  Time since boot:  53 minutes
```

I'm looking to install sipsak from the terminal with macport, coming at this from a Linux perspective.

Comment: Please split your question in two, like: How to install and use macports in Yosemite?(Check if this has already been asked here first) and How to install SIPSAK with macports or homebrew?

Comment: @klanomath fair enough, you're right.  I narrowed the question to just installing sipsak.

Comment: sips does not to be under macports so can't be installed from it (port search sups finds nothing) The comment in the build means it looks for macports libraries but I am not sure. The question still needs clarification and there is no information what sips is the question can be read as if it installs things

Comment: sipsak is the sip swiss army knife for testing sip connections.  sip is, I think, session...protocol.  for voip.  same as what facetime uses.